Airflow service throw an error: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'task_group'
I attempted to retrieve data from MongoDB and input it into the DAG factory creator function, but then Airflow generated an error:
Broken DAG: [/home/jj/airflow/dags/Metrics_calculationsV8_dagFactory.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jj/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 405, in apply_defaults
    task_group = TaskGroupContext.get_current_task_group(dag)
  File "/home/jj/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/utils/task_group.py", line 673, in get_current_task_group
    return dag.task_group
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'task_group'

I'm having trouble locating the line in my DAG code file that needs to be fixed, as the error message doesn't provide a specific line number.
def create_sensor_dag():
    dag_id = f"metrics_calculator_{id}"
    default_args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'start_date': datetime(2024, 4, 21),
        'retries': 1,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=20),
    }

    # Instantiate your DAG
    dag = DAG(
        dag_id=dag_id,
        default_args=default_args,
        description='DAG to calculate the Sensors Metrics',
        # schedule_interval='@daily',  # Set the desired schedule interval
        #start_date= datetime.now(),
        start_date= datetime(2024, 4, 21),
        #schedule_interval='*/1 * * * *',
        schedule_interval='*/15 * * * *',
        catchup=True,
    )


    default_args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'start_date': datetime(2024, 1, 1),
        'retries': 1,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=0.2),
    }

    # Set the task dependencies
    ***
    code
    ***
    return dag


def find_all_measures(**kwargs):
    ***
    code
    ***
    kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='measures_info', value=measures_info)
    return measures_info


def find_all_measure_ids(**kwargs):
    ***
    code
    ***
    kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='all_measure_ids', value=all_measure_ids)
    return list(all_measure_ids)

def Create_DAG_function(dataSource, **kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    is_list = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='find_all_measure_ids_task', key = 'all_measure_ids') 
    for id in id_list:
        globals()[f"metrics_calculator_{id}"] = create_sensor_dag()

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 4, 21),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=20),
}

default_dag = DAG(
    dag_id='create_dag_task',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Default DAG to control the DAG factory',
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
)

# Add the task to run Create_DAG_function
create_dag_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='create_dag_task',
    python_callable=Create_DAG_function,
    op_kwargs={},
    dag=dag,
)

fetch_measure_ids_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='fetch_measure_ids',
    python_callable=find_all_measure_ids,
    op_kwargs={
    },
    dag=dag,
)

fetch_measures_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='find_all_measures_task',
    python_callable=find_all_measures,
    op_kwargs={
    },
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
)


I attempted to reconstruct the logic and dependencies, but unfortunately, I am still encountering errors.

The line(s) that causes your error is the dag=dag in your PythonOperator(s).
You can see that the error message changes if you change the code to be dag="123", for example, it will tell you 'string' object has no attribute 'task_group'.
From my understanding, you would need a valid DAG in order for this to work, and the dag you are passing in is one that gets created in Create_DAG_function. Perhaps changing it to default_dag would work.
create_dag_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='create_dag_task',
    python_callable=Create_DAG_function,
    op_kwargs={},
    dag=default_dag,
)

